# What needs to be done when moving a ruby on rails (RoR) app to a different directory?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I generated the default RoR application with the `rails new <project_name>` command, and everything seemed to go fine.  Later I decided I wanted to relocate my rails projects in a different directory *(something other than my home directory)*, so I moved the RoR project to `/opt/rails/<project_name>` and I created a symlink in my web root pointing to `/opt/rails/<project_name>/public`, and the page loads fine, but some of the assets aren't loading on the Welcome aboard page, i.e. the `rails.png`  And when I go to click on the `About your application's environment` link I get a 404 error.  If I had to take a guess as to why I'm getting these errors it would have to be that I moved the rails app `simple_cms` from `/home/user/www/rails/simple_cms` to `/opt/rails/simple_cms`  Is there a command I need to issue in the project root of `simple_cms` to get things fully working?

**Update**

I'm using Apache 2 as the web server on a CentOS 5.9 box.

Comment: What is your OS? Are you using Apache to serve your Rails app? Normally you can just move the entire folder where ever you want, and then you open up a terminal window, go to that directory, and use `rails s` to start the server. Everything will be served from that folder with the appropriate paths.

Comment: If you inspect the `rails.png` graphic in the browser, what path is is showing, i.e. is it a relative path? Have you tried `rake assets:clean` and then `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: I haven't tried the `rake assets:clean` yet, and the path for the `rails.png` is `assets/rails.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `rails s` to launch your app, then there is no need to create symlinks. The web server (could be WEBrick, or Thin) will serve the application from the app root.

If you are using Apache or Nginx, again there is no need to create symlinks, but you need to let Apache/Nginx know the new location. For example, in a Nginx+Passenger setup, you would need to set `passenger_app_root` to the new location.

Provide more details in your question, or consult the documentation for your setup.